# Why did Dumbledore not introduce Prof. Quirrell at the beginning of the year?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, defence-against-the-dark-arts

As there is a new DADA teacher every year, Dumbledore announces the new teacher every year at the beginning. Every year except the first. Did J.K. Rowling ever explain (in canon) why Dumbledore did not introduce Quirrell as a new teacher then?

Comment: Are you talking about the film or the book?

Comment: What strikes me as more strange is why he didn't introduce the new Muggle Studies teacher, Charity Burbage.  He was likely new that year, because Professor Quirrel was teaching Muggle Studies.

Comment: Because he was hosting Voldemort's part soul..

Comment: @b_jonas That seems to be the real question here, as Quirrel wasn't a new teacher.

Comment: I might suggest the answer is because he didn't need to. To us, nor to Harry. We already knew as much about him as an introduction would give us, so it wasn't neccessary to have another introduction (we were introduced to him in Diagon Alley, and I know your question is an introduction in Hogwarts but it has the same purpose). But, was Quirell even knew at Harry's first year?

Comment: @MacCooper New to the position, but not as a teacher at Hogwarts, apparently.

Comment: When Hagrid took over the Care of Magical creatures job he was introduced at the start of term feast, and so was Snape/Slughorn, so it would stand to reason that Quirrel/Burbage would both be announced at the feast as well.

Comment: I'd suspect that this is simply an inconsistency in the books. Are you looking for a canon answer (interviews, Pottermore, etc.)?

Comment: @BP_Phoenix, I would suggest again that it's just because we don't need another introduction. With Hagrid it was character development, and with Snape/Slughorn it was a plot twist. Burbage was unimportant in her entirety until Book 7, and we were already introduced to Quirrel in Diagon Alley: his Hogwarts introduction was unneccesary.

Comment: Maybe he was introduced while the first years, including Harry, were waiting outside to be sorted?  Because, why would first years care about staff changes?

Comment: @Zoredache: In *Half-Blood Prince*, Harry misses the Sorting, but still hears staff announcements. They seem to get rolled into all the start-of-term announcements, which first years do need to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer I can give is that it was not necessary to introduce him that year, because he was already introduced. Meaning that that was not his first year at Hogwarts. He probably taught there for a year or so.

Another Theory is that since this is the first book, she was still learning her writing styles and how she was going to write the story. The first book was the first book, the series wasn't cemented, yet. But almost all of that is calculated conjecture.

> "Oh, yeah. Poor bloke. Brilliant mind. He was fine while he was studyin' outta books but then he took a year off ter get some firsthand experience..." —Rubeus Hagrid on Quirrell's youth.

That is from the [Harry Potter wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quirinus_Quirrell).

> After teaching Muggle Studies for some time, he took a year-long sabbatical in 1990 in order to "gain first-hand experience",[4] though in reality he had taken a 'Grand Tour' around the world in order to hopefully find whatever remained of Lord Voldemort after his first defeat, partly out of curiosity, partly out of that unacknowledged desire for importance from his childhood. At the very least, Quirrell fantasised that he could be the man who tracked Voldemort down, but at best, might learn skills from Voldemort that would ensure he was never laughed at again. His journey proved successful as he did indeed find Voldemort, though he was no match for the Dark Lord (even in such a weakened state) and when he realised that Quirinus had a position at Hogwarts, Voldemort used his charisma to manipulate Quirrell to serve him. Quirrell also adopted a turban for everyday use after this sabbatical, claiming to have received it from an African prince as compensation for disposing of a zombie.

Once again from the [wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quirinus_Quirrell). I have no proof this is true though, because on page 134, Chapter 8 of the first book when it is supposed to have occurred some but not all of this told.

You could also try reading the last chapter.

Comment: He can't have been there for longer than a year THE JINX OF VOLDEMORT!

Comment: @Simon the jinx applies only to DADA-teachers. Quirrel taught muggle studies beforehand, and after one year as DADA teacher he "left"...

Comment: @Benedikt Yeah at the time of writing I interpreted OPs statement incorrectly. I realised but forgot about my comment, Oh well!

Comment: This is an excellent out-of-canon answer, but I am looking for a in-canon answer. However, there might not be a in-canon answer, so I accept this.